# Export/Checkout a Specific Revision Files from SVN Command Line

Tags: svn, command-line, export, revision

Iam trying to export/checkout a specific revision from my repository from SVN command line. How do I get files from a specific revision, only the modified files.

Say, If revision#457 has 3 file modification, I need to pull only these 3 files from repository.
    I tried:-

```
    svn co -r 457 https://test.repo.com/branches/1.0.X
    svn export --force -r 457 https://test.repo.com/branches/1.0.X ./
```

Both seems to be pulling all the files. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must only get the files that have changed, I believe you will have to do this per file via some scripting.

You can get the files which were modified for a specific commit with `-c` options:

```
svn diff -c457 --summarize
```

Parse the output and use `svn cat` or sparse checkouts to download the files.